# Getting the current scroll position in Chrome using scrollTop() on page load/refresh

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, scrolltop

Running the following in Chrome always returns 0:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
     console.log($(window).scrollTop());
});
```

Running that same command via the console:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Does return the correct number. (i.e.: 843)

There are a lot of questions about this issue here on StackOverflow but none of them have given me a correct working answer or alternative.
I'm at a loss...

Comment: Are you talking about loading an URL that points to a named anchor on the page, f.ex: example.com/#section ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `scrollTop()` returns the current vertical position of the scroll bar. Typically on page load, the scroll bar is at position `0`. If the console prints out something else, then you *or the browser* must have scrolled down before the function was called.

If you are using named anchors or refreshing the page from a scrolled position, you can bind a handler to the scroll event that only triggers once - on page load:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    console.log( $(this).scrollTop() );
});
```

Comment: That is why the question says page load/refresh. Because with a refresh the browser retains its scroll position and that is exactly what I'm looking after.

Comment: I clarified the answer to point out that the solution also covers the auto-scroll feature some browsers have on refresh.

Comment: @David I found this Q&A very useful but I've realized that if I bind the handler to the `scroll` event it always returns 0 (because the browser hasn't scrolled, so you need to scroll first to see the value change). While if I bind it to the `load` event, it returns the scrolled position where I am (Chrome v30, Firefox v24).

Comment: very good and clever solution for getting browser's back button cached scroll value, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get the current scroll position In page

1. First get pageYOffSet
   `let verticalScrollOffset = window.pageYOffset;`

   then Set
    `window.scrollTo(0,verticalScrollOffset);`
2. If you need both Side position and set then

   ```
   let scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
   let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

   window.scrollTo(scrollLeft,scrollTop);
   ```
3. Using **ViewportScroller** [click here to know more](https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller)
   `this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(this.viewportScroller.getScrollPosition());`//does not helps in my case
4. **Ideal Solution** works for me, I just save verticalScrollOffset(YaxisSrollPosition) before loading the page or refresh in any constant variable or local storage.Then After Refresh or load the page Use that position

   ```
   let verticalScrollOffset = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: verticalScrollOffset }, "slow");//slow Or fast option
   ```